# how to make content overly a clip-path shape div?

Tags: css, reactjs, polygon

For my header div, I've set a clip-path polygon and I would like my content, more specific - an image,  to be on top of that shape, currently, it is being cut.

I tried to give z-index to the elements,
also, I tried to use a sub div for that shape only

```html
<div className="header">
            <HomeNav />

            <div className="header-content">

                <div className="header-text">
                    <h1>title</h1>
                    <p>text text text</p>
                    <button className="btn btn-start">click</button>
                </div>

                <div className="header-pic">
                    <img alt="some pic" src={test}></img>
                </div>

            </div>

         </div>
```

```css
.header{
    background-image: linear-gradient(210deg, #3f2b96, #a8c0ff);    
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80vh, 0 90%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 70vh, 0 80%);


    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 14vh 86vh;
}
```

I expect the picture to be on top of the polygon so that 50% of it will be after the ending line of the polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is impossible because `clip-path` will clip the element and all its content.

You can try to build the shape differently using skew transformation like below:

```css
.header {
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
}
.header:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:skewY(-5deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(215deg, #3f2b96, #a8c0ff);;
}
img {
 display:block;
 margin: 10px 10px 0 auto;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/200/200">
</div>
```